# Windows Terminal WSL2 profile shortcut not highlighted in taskbar when opened

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, taskbar, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I have a shortcut for a WSL2 profile in Windows Terminal (Windows 10) pinned to the taskbar. The command is of the form `wt.exe -p "Fedora 36"` where the profile executes the command `wsl.exe ~ -d fedora`. When I open this shortcut the Windows Terminal icon is highlighted in the taskbar which is the expected behaviour. But I want the shortcut icon to highlight instead when this profile is opened. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: The shortcut is not a window, so its icon cannot contain the window of Terminal.